# PHP- Get index/associated value of option selected in dropdown box

Tags: php, drop-down-menu

I want to show values in a dropdown box (either from an array or database - please advise on which option is method)

Then

when a user selects a value in dropdown box, i want to have and get its associated index value (like 1, 2).

For example: dropdown box shows values:

"Car"
"Bicycle"

If user selects "Car", when i get dropdown selected value, i should get 1,  similarly for "Bicycle" i get 2   .. and so on.

Please advise easy and simplest method to implement this

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two methods:

1) Set up prior to display a code that holds associative array with key -> value i.e: 1 => Car (you can keep it in config file if it doesn't change frequently, you can pull it from database or you can keep it in some other form: serialized, file etc.) and use it when the submitted form is being processed.

2) Use array with key and value with the same string i.e: Car => Car and when the form is processed you will have value right away. This solution has some limitations and be troublesome with using more words or other characters that need to be sanitized.

I would advise option 1, you will have to set up the list before and use it after form has been processed but it allows more freedom and its less maintenance.

Comment: Thanks. I did it! I used associative array. 

Now, i want to get selected value of the dropdown box. If dropdown selected value is "Car", how will i get "Car"'s  associative value?

I am here:

$vehicle=$_POST['Vehicle_Type']; // I NEED SOMETHING HERE?

something like this/ please help?

$vehicle=$_POST[arr'Vehicle_Type'];

Comment: Ok, for example you have array: `$f_select = array(1=>'Car',2=>'Bicycle');` use that array to print `<select name='transport'>` form field and its options, when user selects one of the options and submits the form you will have to invoke `$f_select` array and to get value of `$vehicle` just use this: `$vehicle = $f_select[$_POST['transport'];` and you will have in that variable appropriate value.

Comment: Lukas,

$vehicle=$bg_arr[$_POST['Vehicle_Type']]; --  This gives me "Car" not its associative value 1 .... 

note: bg_arr is my associative array
$bg_arr = array('0' => 'Car', '1' => 'Bike');

i dont wan to change it to this, 
$bg_arr = array('Car' => '0', 'Bike' => '1');

otherwise my dropdown will show 0,1 not "Car", "Bike"

Comment: perhaps there may be two other options as below,plz confirm (but i want to keep short and simple code)

1. use one assosiative array for displaying values, and another associative value to use when getting value from dropdown.

2.using multi-dimential array ???

Comment: Selected key in that form field is contained in `$_POST['Vehicle_Type']` so you don't need to do anything to get that information just invoke `$vehicle=$_POST['Vehicle_Type'];` and you will get index value (array key)

Comment: with key i am getting its value but with value i failed to get its key...i tried your code example but i dont key key :( please help

Comment: Ok from the beggining, user selects "Car" in form and submits it. To get the value of that index key use: `$vehicle = $bg_arr[$_POST['Vehicle_Type'];` to get just only index key use: `$vehicle=$_POST['Vehicle_Type'];`

Comment: i tried but it is not letting me. requiring 15 reputation to do this.. i am sorry :(

Comment: You can choose my answer as accepted (that should be available to you I think).